# what is correct format of database table structure

Tags: database-normalization

Is anybody tell me that if the database structure I create a single table to store multiple banners and templates for different event types like below is good database system. when we know will keep updating adding removing banners and template from admin side. Will it fulfill relational database and normalization rules.Also which approach is better for less query execution time.

A)table1

Event_type_id    Key             value

1                Small_banners   Baneer1;banner2;banner3

2    Template    Temp1;temp2;temp3

.....

……

Or instead create 2 tables like below is good approach

B)  - banner table

```
 <p>Id  event_type_id    value</p>
```

1            1           baner_1.jpg

2           1           baner_3.jpg

3            2           banner_4.jpg

.....

And second table for template

-Template table

Id     event_type_id   value

1          1           temp_1.jpg

2          1           temp_2.jpg

3          2           temp_3.jpg

......

C) **One more thing having 50s of rows in a single table is better or we should split it in multiple tables.**
**Please suggest with reasons.**

Comment: See my comments at https://stackoverflow.com/q/51172997/3404097.

Answer (score 0):

Going by rules of normalisation, it is always good to keep different table instead of inserting comma separated values in a single field.

But new database like Postgres supports json data to be stored in fields and also querying them.