# Best practice for setting non-normalized columns in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, database-normalization

Question to all Yii2 normalization geeks out there.

Where is the best place to set non-normalized columns in Yii2?

Example, I have models **Customer**, **Branch**, **CashRegister**, and **Transaction**. 
In a perfect world, and in a perfectly normalized Database, our **Transaction** model would have only the `cashregister_id`, The **CashRegister** would store `branch_id`, and the **Branch** would store `customer_id`. However due to performance issues, we find ourselves obliged sometimes though to have a **non-normalized** **Transaction** model containing the following:

1. cashregister_id
2. branch_id
3. customer_id

When creating a transaction, I want to store all 3 values. Setting

```
$transaction->branch_id = $transaction->cashRegister->branch_id;
$transaction->customer_id = $transaction->cashRegister->branch->customer_id;
```

however in the controller does not feel correct.

One solution would be to do this in **aftersave()** in the **Transaction** model and make those columns read-only. But this also seems better but not perfect.

I wanted to know what is the best practice or where is the best place to set those duplicate columns, to make sure that the data integrity is maintained?

Comment: post sample controller code to illustrate your issue. I dont understand why you have to do `$transaction->branch_id = $transaction->cashRegister->cashregister_id;`

Comment: This is just a conceptual question. But what I mean is, in the transaction I need to save the branch_id and the customer_id. This goes against the normalization principles of course since I can get customer_id and branch_id from joining Branch and CashRegister tables respectively.

Comment: I added another line. I hope this makes the question clearer :)

Comment: you are trying to get `$transaction->branch_id` from same transaction's `cashRegister`.  Since it is the same object, then your concept is confusing. If you really need to write something that makes sense, include also your "conceptual"  controller as well.

Comment: Hi. Time to read a textbook on information modeling & database design. You are asking us to reproduce one & apply it. You need to read one & follow it. PS "does not feel correct" does not mean anything. "better" & "perfect" don't mean anything. Explain yourself. To be on-topic give exact designs & criteria by which one could decide.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: @philipxy I get what you mean. I edited the question to be a bit more specific. My data isn't normalized, this is a fact that I cant change now, is this is a project that I started working on long after it started. What I can do however, is reduce the negative effect of de-normalization by controlling how the columns are set. And this is what my question is about :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a DB-only solution.

I assume your relations are:

- A customer has many branches
- A branch has many cashregisters
- A cashregister has many transactions

The corresponding schema could be:

```sql
create table customers (
    customer_id int auto_increment,
    customer_data text,
    primary key (customer_id)
);

create table branches (
    branch_id int auto_increment,
    customer_id int not null,
    branch_data text,
    primary key (branch_id),
    index (customer_id),
    foreign key (customer_id) references customers(customer_id)
);

create table cashregisters (
    cashregister_id int auto_increment,
    branch_id int not null,
    cashregister_data text,
    primary key (cashregister_id),
    index (branch_id),
    foreign key (branch_id) references branches(branch_id)
);

create table transactions (
    transaction_id int auto_increment,
    cashregister_id int not null,
    transaction_data text,
    primary key (transaction_id),
    index (cashregister_id),
    foreign key (cashregister_id) references cashregisters(cashregister_id)
);
```

(Note: This should be part of your question - so we wouldn't need to guess.)

If you want to include redundant columns (`branch_id` and `customer_id`) in the `transactions` table, you should make them part of the foreign key. But first you will need to include a `customer_id` column in the `cashregisters` table and also make it part of the foreign key.

The extended schema would be:

```sql
create table customers (
    customer_id int auto_increment,
    customer_data text,
    primary key (customer_id)
);

create table branches (
    branch_id int auto_increment,
    customer_id int not null,
    branch_data text,
    primary key (branch_id),
    index (customer_id, branch_id),
    foreign key (customer_id) references customers(customer_id)
);

create table cashregisters (
    cashregister_id int auto_increment,
    branch_id int not null,
    customer_id int not null,
    cashregister_data text,
    primary key (cashregister_id),
    index (customer_id, branch_id, cashregister_id),
    foreign key (customer_id, branch_id)
        references branches(customer_id, branch_id)
);

create table transactions (
    transaction_id int auto_increment,
    cashregister_id int not null,
    branch_id int not null,
    customer_id int not null,
    transaction_data text,
    primary key (transaction_id),
    index (customer_id, branch_id, cashregister_id),
    foreign key (customer_id, branch_id, cashregister_id)
        references cashregisters(customer_id, branch_id, cashregister_id)
);
```

Notes:

- Any foreign key constraint needs an index in the child (referencing) and the parent (referenced) table, which can support the constraint check. The given column order in the keys allows us to define the schema with only one index per table.
- A foreign key should always reference a unique key in the parent table. However in this example the composition of referenced columns is (at least) implicitly unique, because it contains the primary key. In almost any other RDBMS you would need to define the indices in the "middle" tables (`branches` and `cashregisters`) as `UNIQUE`. This however is not necessary in MySQL.
- The composite foreign keys will take care of the data integrity/consistency. Example: If you have a branch entry with `branch_id = 2` and `customer_id = 1` - you wan't be able to insert a cashregister with `branch_id = 2` and `customer_id = 3`, because this would violate the foreign key constraint.
- You will probably need more indices for your queries. Most probably you will need `cashregisters(branch_id)` and `transactions(cashregister_id)`. With these indices you might not even need to change your ORM relation code. (though AFAIK *Yii* supports composite foreign keys.)
- You can define relations like "*customer has many transactions*". Previously you would need to use "*has many through*", involving two middle/bridge tables. This will save you two joins in many cases.

If you want the redundant data to be maintained by the database, you can use the following triggers:

```sql
create trigger cashregisters_before_insert
before insert on cashregisters for each row
    set new.customer_id = (
        select b.customer_id
        from branches b
        where b.branch_id = new.branch_id
    )
;

delimiter $$
create trigger transactions_before_insert
before insert on transactions for each row
begin
    declare new_customer_id, new_branch_id int;
    select c.customer_id, c.branch_id into new_customer_id, new_branch_id
        from cashregisters c
        where c.cashregister_id = new.cashregister_id;
    set new.customer_id = new_customer_id;
    set new.branch_id   = new_branch_id;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Now you can insert new entries without defining the redundant values:

```sql
insert into cashregisters (branch_id, cashregister_data) values
    (2, 'cashregister 1'),
    (1, 'cashregister 2');

insert into transactions (cashregister_id, transaction_data) values
    (2, 'transaction 1'),
    (1, 'transaction 2');
```

See demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fE7kVxiTcZBX3gfA81nJzE/0

If your business logic allows to update the relations, you should extend your foreign keys with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. This will make the changes through the relation chain down to the `transactions` table.

Comment: Thank youi very much, this is the answer I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem once and using `afterSave()` or `beforeSave()` looked as a great solution at the beginning, but finally resulted  hard to maintain spaghetti code. I ended up with creating separate component for managing such relations. Something like:

```
class TransactionsManager extends Component {

    public function createTransaction(TransactionInfo $info, CashRegister $register) {
        // magic
    }
}
```

Then you're not creating or updating `Transaction` model directly, you're alway using this component and encapsulates all logic in it. Then ActiveRecord works more like a data representation and does not contain any advanced business logic. It looks more complicated in some cases than `$model->load($data) && $model->save()` but after all it is much easier to maintain when you have all logic in one place and you don't need to debug `save()` calls chains (one model runs `save()` of different model in `afterSave()` which runs `save()` of different model in `afterSave()`... and so on).

Comment: You mean something like a Factory holding all the logic?

Comment: Kind of. The point is to put logic for transactions management (including creating, updating and deleting) in one place, but not i active record itself.

Comment: But the point here is that I want to make sure that those columns arent touched. I considered using triggers, any ideas about those? :)

Comment: And thanks for the answer, I upvoted it. But this is not exactly what I'm looking for here. What I'm looking for rather is where to set all those un-normalized columns to make sure I wont lose data integrity :)

Comment: Keeping management logic in one place may help you maintain code responsible for database operations, but if you want to keep data integrity and you don't trust your code (or different apps modifying this database) then this should be implemented at database level. No AR magic will help you if someone will update database directly using raw queries.

Comment: This makes sense @rob006. I think in the end this is going to be the solution that ill go with, creating triggers in the db so that those columns get automatically updated. And adding read-only to the properties in the models to prevent them from being edited.